# How are the three sectors on an F1 track determined?

Tags: formula-1

I know that there are three sectors in each F1 track, coloured red, blue, and yellow. But how is the track divided up into these sectors? Are they all the same length (i.e. if a track is 3km then each sector is 1km)? Or is there some F1 regulation covering this?

Comment: aren't they actually purple, green and yellow?

Comment: Thats how the current sector is going. the red/blue/yellow are in the track previews.

Comment: @CGCampbell Purple, Green and Yellow is stands for timing for each sector. Red, Blue and Yellow stands for parts of each sector.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no straight science of 'all sectors should be the same length or the same time'.

Looking at the Canadian GP
[image]

Just giving it a quick look over, its not distance. The red sector is clearly shorter.

For times, looking at the times of FP1 of 2022: https://www.reddit.com/r/formula1/comments/veo0re/canadian_gp_2022fp1_sector_times/

Sector 1: 20s. 2:24s. 3:29s. So not time either.

My best bet is that is at the discretion of the track owners. There is rules that you should try to make the equal as much as possible, but also, and that would be the main rule, that sectors should be split where the sector change is in a 'neutral' place. Where there is not a part of 'its in the middle of a turn so the times change depending on what point of the turn you are.